# AngularFire - Firestore - How to get sub collection and merge into HTML

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire5

I have a scenario at the moment where I have a collection of issues which i successfully fetch. In firestore, each issue (`issues > issueID`) has a sub-collection called `images`.

In that collection there are doc id's per image. (`issues > issueID > images > imageID`). I have a page that's displaying **all** issues, and I'd like to show all related image per issue also.

In my HTML below i have added a comment of where i would like the issue images to go.

Desired result:

- Issue 1

  - Issue 1 images
- Issue 2

  - Issue 2 images

etc

**Get Issues**

```
 this.issuesCollection = this.afs.collection<any>(`users/${this.userID}/projects/${this.project_id}/issues`, ref => ref.orderBy('issue_order'));
      // this.issues = this.issuesCollection.valueChanges();   
      this.issues = this.issuesCollection.snapshotChanges().pipe(
        map(actions => actions.map(a => {
          const data = a.payload.doc.data();
          const id = a.payload.doc.id;
          return { id, ...data };
        }))
      );
```

**HTML**

```
<ul>
   <li *ngFor="let issue of issues | async">
      {{issue.issue_title}}
      <ul>
         <li>
             <!-- THIS IS WHERE I WOULD LIKE THE IMAGES PER ISSUE TO GO -->      
         </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**Images Collection Reference**
This is the location of the images, where `id` would be the ID of the issue. This hasn't been hooked up, but is where the location of the images would be.

```
this.imagesCollection = this.afs.collection<any>(`users/${this.userID}/projects/${this.project_id}/issues/${id}/images`);
this.images = this.imagesCollection.snapshotChanges()
```

Answer (score 2):

There is new feature in firebase called [Collection group query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query), which definitely can help in your case. But unfortunately i dont think this has been already implemented in angularfire2.

You can use `RxJS` `MergeMap`

```
  const collection = this.firestore.collection('users');
  return  collection.valueChanges.pipe(
    mergeMap( (users: User[]) =>  
               this.firestore.doc(`stories/${users[0].uid}`).
                        valueChanges().pipe(map(
                          (storie) => Object.assign({}, {users[0].uid, ...users[0], ...stories}
                      ))
           ))
   );
```